# Cannot disable Excel backup settings from custom Save As dialog / VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file, where we have created a custom sub that, when saving, presents the user with a Save As dialog that limits the list of available file types a user can save as.  This has been used by a company for several years as a template - so they have hundreds of excel files saved in various locations with the following macro in it:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' If user is doing a 'Save As', set the file type as "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook",
    ' and set the list of available extensions they can save as.
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xFileExt As String
    
    If SaveAsUI <> False Then
        Cancel = True
        xFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("<job name goes here> CHANNEL SCHEDULE", "CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv," _
                                                                                         & "Excel Macro-Enabled Template (*.xltm), *.xltm," _
                                                                                         & "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," _
                                                                                         & "Excel Workbook (MACROS DISABLED) (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," _
                                                                                         & "", 3, "Save As xlsm file")

        If xFileName <> "False" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            ' Get the file extension.
            xFileExt = Right(xFileName, Len(xFileName) - InStrRev(xFileName, "."))
            ' Save the file.
            Select Case xFileExt
                Case "csv"
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
                Case "xltm"
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
                Case "xlsm"
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
                Case "xlsx"
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

                Case Else
                    MsgBox "Error saving as the selected file type.  Please try again, or try a different file type.  Sorry."
            End Select
          
          Application.EnableEvents = True
        
        Else
          'MsgBox "Save As Operation Cancelled."
          Cancel = True
          Exit Sub
        
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

That same file also happens to have "Always create backup" setting enabled as shown in the photo below, so that when any of these files are opened excel automatically creates a file in the same dir as the file just opened called "*Backup of < file name you just opened >*".

---

**The problem is that now they need to disable this feature on all their excel documents, or at least give an end-user the ability to disable it themselves so they can do it manually.**

The only way I have found to disable this feature is by going to Save As > Tools > General Options:
[image: Save As dialog > Tools drop-down > General Options dialog]

---

**However**, when using the `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` method, the "General Options" option from the Tools dropdown is no longer available as shown below:
[image: Save As dialog > Tools drop-down]

---

**My questions:**

1. Is there another from the excel GUI to disable the "Always create backup" setting if they cannot get to it from their current Save As dialogs?
2. Or is there another way to 'enable' the General Options dialog from the custom Save As dialog creaed by the `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` method?
3. Is there a way to programmatically change (disable) this backup setting?

Comment: Not sure if this overrides the setting, e.g. `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`. Please share your experience.

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes, thank you!  Modifying the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs does then disable that setting in the saved file.  That is half my battle.  Do you know if it is also possible to set this property?  ActiveWorkbook.CreateBackup = False does not work as it is a read-only property.

Comment: Can you use Workbook.SaveAs to override the setting? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas It’s an option as a parameter.

Comment: I guess that after you save the file with `CreateBackup:=False`, its `Workbook.CreateBackup` property is set to `False`, and vice versa. `CreateBackup:=False` is probably the default behavior when you save a new file unless you explicitly save it with `CreateBackup:=True`.

Comment: Saving the file with the CreateBackup:=False flag does the trick.  If you would like to answer below I can accept it and close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to VBasic2008 and Skin in the comments above.

Adding the `CreateBackup:=False` flag to the save/save as process will disable the "Always create backup" setting.

So:
`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV`

Changes to:
`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`